# Which quantile calculation method(s) does GRASS-GIS use?

Tags: grass-gis

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample) , there are 9 common methods of calculating quantiles in common use across various statistical software packages, as well as languages like R and Python. Various other custom implementations are also possible.

In GRASS, several tools offer quantile calculation (r.neighbour, r.series, r.quantile, etc) but the exact method in use is not specified in any of the tool manuals or in source code comments. I can't read the source code itself clearly enough to figure out which method is in use (or even if the same method is used consistently across these tools).

Can anyone explain how GRASS handles this issue, so that it can be compared with other software?

EDIT:
Someone on twitter pointed out a [recent commit](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/commit/c700a8a923cd8e7b0e49e5abab3a2ae313eccaef) showing that `r.quantile` and `r.stats.quantile` will be using Type 7 going forward - but this is only a few days old at 2022-01-26 and so will be pinned to an upcoming release. I'm still not sure what current/past state does.

Comment: Could you add a link to corresponding place in the source code to help those who could possibly interpret it?

Comment: It is the pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/2108 which has now also been backported to the upcoming GRASS GIS 8.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page you referenced specifies methods for **estimating** quantiles from a **sample**. I think that GRASS uses the full raster for calculating quantiles, so these 9 estimation methods are not relevant.

The way GRASS calculates quantiles is specified in the [source](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/blob/main/raster/r.quantile/main.c) as follows:

```
/* get zero-based rank for quantile */
/* generic formula for one-based rank
 * rank = quant * (N + 1 - 2C) + C
 * with quant = quantile, N = number of values, C = constant
 * common values for C:
 * C = 0
 *   rank = quant * (N + 1)
 *   recommended by NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology)
 *   https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc262.htm
 * C = 0.5
 *   rank = quant * N + 0.5
 *   Matlab
 * C = 1
 *   rank = quant * (N - 1) + 1
 *   numpy, R, MS Excel, ...
 *   Noted as an alternative by NIST */
```

So from my understanding of the code (line 80) GRASS uses the method recommended by NIST.
Does that help?

Comment: Kind of. Given that most rasters are a discretised model of a continuous field, the sample vs population concept gets a bit wobbly. Most raster programs will attempt to compute off all cells if memory permits, or take a random sample of cells when ncell is large, as R's raster package does. I think the reference to that NIST link implies that R6 was in use in GRASS < 8.0.1? And there seems to be some kind of binning approach in use to manage memory but once again, I can't really read C code very well. I may be misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent GRASS GIS enhancement (https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/2108) the algorithm used in GRASS has been changed to algorithm type 7 as described in Hyndman and Fan (1996; https://doi.org/10.2307/2684934). It is also used by R (see `?quantile` for a description of the different algorithms) and numpy.

The enhancement has been published in Feb. 2022 with [GRASS GIS 8.0.1](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/releases/tag/8.0.1).

Edit: fix URL to code change.

Comment: Thanks for documenting the future state on this answer. Are you able to confirm whether R6 was the previous approach?

Comment: Sorry, I had put the wrong link. Fixed now. According to https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/2108 the old algorithm previously used in GRASS is not listed in the paper. Now it has become no. 7.